# SSRS reporting service UAC error, already tried everything

Tags: reporting-services, permissions, uac

Been trying to get SSRS reporting service set up for a while now, and been stuck on the issue with UAC.

After setting up the Reporting Service Configuration Manager settings, with service account using my PC's login account, Database using ReportServer$SQLEXPRESS, etc. when launching the server @ 127.0.0.1/Reports it directs me to 127.0.0.1/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx and then after login with my PC's login this is what I get on my browser -

"User 'OCTETHP\Support' does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed."

And I have done my researches online, I turned off UAC, I am on the administrator account, and I also tried to run the browser with right click to run as administrator option on both chrome and IE. Still does not solve this problem. Could anyone help me out with this??

I am currently running on windows 8.1. Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried giving user OCTETHP\Support the required permissions?

Comment: It is set as administrator already, and I also try run the IE as admin. Not sure what other permissions I have to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely the problem is with the account the reporting server is running under (OCTETHP\Support). You may need to add this user to the web user group (IIS_WPG depending on your OS version). If that doesn't work, you can set the user to be a local administrator and work the permissions back from there.

If you want to run the reporting services from another account you'd want to follow these steps:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Under websites locate the SSRS website (/Reports in your case)
3. In basic properties check the App Pool the site is running under
4. Go to the App Pools section of IIS and open the advanced properties
5. Setup the user that the App Pool runs under

You'll need to make sure the user is assigned to the web user group, and has permissions to access the folder that the website points to.

Comment: hi, Thanks for your respones!, So I changed the login user to Administrator and now it works. But from what you were saying earlier, I do not see the /Report website under my IIS, is there some step I missed that I should be doing? thanks